# using sed or awk to parse multipath output

Tags: linux, bash, sed, awk

I'm trying to parse multipath output on linux for a script I am writing, and I can't quite find the correct SED or AWK syntax to get it how I want it.  I've been browsing various sites and stackoverflow examples without much luck.

I want to find a way to make:

```
temp (360a98000572d4d2d5834566c64536b46) dm-4 NETAPP,LUN
[size=20G]
2:0:0:4  sde        8:64  [active][ready]
1:0:0:4  sdm        8:192 [active][ready]
redo (360a98000572d4d2d5834566c646c366c) dm-3 NETAPP,LUN
[size=5.0G]
2:0:0:3  sdd        8:48  [active][ready]
1:0:0:3  sdl        8:176 [active][ready]
```

look like:

```
temp (360a98000572d4d2d5834566c64536b46) dm-4 NETAPP,LUN [size=20G] 2:0:0:4  sde        8:64  active][ready]
temp (360a98000572d4d2d5834566c64536b46) dm-4 NETAPP,LUN [size=20G] 1:0:0:4  sdm        8:192 [active][ready]
redo (360a98000572d4d2d5834566c646c366c) dm-3 NETAPP,LUN [size=5.0G] 2:0:0:3  sdd        8:48  [active][ready]
redo (360a98000572d4d2d5834566c646c366c) dm-3 NETAPP,LUN [size=5.0G] 1:0:0:3  sdl        8:176 [active][ready]
```

** Edit
Ok, so making this even harder, I have found multipath configurations without Netapp's default settings.  This makes it so that NETAPP,LUN is not guarenteed to be on the line.  What I've started to do:

```
/sbin/multipath -ll | grep -v "round-robin"| sed 's/\[feat.*//g' | sed ':a; $!N;s/\n\([^\n]*\[size\)/ \1/;ta;P;D'
```

which puts size on the main line to give me something else to match:

```
360a98000572d4d2d5834664e68323436 dm-6 NETAPP,LUN [size=50G]
\_ 1:0:0:0  sda 8:0   [active][ready]
360a98000572d4d2d5834664e68395951 dm-7 NETAPP,LUN [size=275G]
\_ 1:0:0:7  sdb 8:16  [active][ready]
```

However I can't get any of the examples below to match  "G[$"  (I know that I will need to have another line for T if there are any terrabyte volumes) and give me the correct output.

Thanks for everyones suggestions below
**End Edit

I know how to clean up spacing, so I will do that after I can get the output correct.  The Lines that will begin the multipath information all end with "LUN".  The servers can have anywhere from one to 8 paths under each LUN line (the sdx devices).  The part before the "()" can either be text (an alias), or numeric.

Answer (score 2):

One way:

Content of `script.awk`:

```
$1 ~ /^([[:digit:]]:){3}[[:digit:]]$/ {
    printf "%s %s\n", line, $0; 
    next;
}

##$1 ~ /temp|redo/ {
$0 ~ /LUN$/ {
    getline l;
    line = $0 " " l;
}
```

Assuming `infile` with the content of the question, run the script like:

```
awk -f script.awk infile
```

With following output:

```
temp (360a98000572d4d2d5834566c64536b46) dm-4 NETAPP,LUN [size=20G] 2:0:0:4  sde        8:64  [active][ready]                                                                                                                                
temp (360a98000572d4d2d5834566c64536b46) dm-4 NETAPP,LUN [size=20G] 1:0:0:4  sdm        8:192 [active][ready]                                                                                                                                
redo (360a98000572d4d2d5834566c646c366c) dm-3 NETAPP,LUN [size=5.0G] 2:0:0:3  sdd        8:48  [active][ready]                                                                                                                               
redo (360a98000572d4d2d5834566c646c366c) dm-3 NETAPP,LUN [size=5.0G] 1:0:0:3  sdl        8:176 [active][ready]
```

Comment: But what if the beginning doesn't start with temp or redo.  Some servers aren't using aliases so they have numerics instead:

360a98000572d4d2d5834664e68323436 dm-6 NETAPP,LUN
[size=50G][features=1 queue_if_no_path][hwhandler=0][rw]
\_ round-robin 0 [prio=2][active]
 \_ 1:0:0:0  sda 8:0   [active][ready]
360a98000572d4d2d5834664e68395951 dm-7 NETAPP,LUN
[size=275G][features=1 queue_if_no_path][hwhandler=0][rw]
\_ round-robin 0 [prio=2][active]
 \_ 1:0:0:7  sdb 8:16  [active][ready]

Comment: This worked pretty good with a couple servers I tested against, but then I found a server whose multipath is misconfigured resulting in Netapp, Lun  not being present.  With the additional information I provided in the post, is it possible to modify your awk script to work based upon [size=xG]?

Answer (score 1):

I don't know the exact specification of input, but this one-liner may help you:

`awk '{if (/LUN$/){ prefix = $0; getline; prefix = prefix " " $0 } else {print prefix, $0} }'`

1. It checks if current line ends with LUN(by matching it against the `/LUN$/` regex)
2. If there is match, it concatenates current line with the next(using `getline` and implicit concatenation operator)
3. If there is no match, it outputs current record along with `prefix`

PS: you may need additional line filtering, which shouldn't be hard, just add another `if` in the `else` branch.

Answer (score 1):

This might work for you (GNU sed):

```
sed '/LUN$/{N;y/\n/ /;h;d};G;s/^\([^\n]*\)\n\(.*\)/\2 \1/' file
```

Explanation:

- `/LUN$/{N;y/\n/ /;h;d}` For lines ending in `LUN` append a newline and then the following line to the pattern space (PS), replace the newline by a space, store the PS in the hold space (HS) and then delete the PS and star the next cycle.
- `G` for all other lines (path lines), append a newline followed by the contents of the HS in the PS.
- `s/^\([^\n]*\)\n\(.*\)/\2 \1/` swap anything upto the first newline with anything following it and replace the newline by a space i.e. append the header information to the path line.

Answer (score 0):

Using sed:

```
sed -n '
  # if this is header append the size line
  /LUN$/{
    N;
    s/\n/ /;
    h       # and remember this
  }; 
  # if not header then append to header
  /LUN \[/!{ 
    G; 
    s/\(.*\)\n\(.*\)/\2 \1/;
    p; #and print
  }' input_file
```

Without comments:

```
 sed -n ' /LUN$/{ N; s/\n/ /; h  }; /LUN \[/!{ G; s/\(.*\)\n\(.*\)/\2 \1/; p; }' input_file
```

Answer (score 0):

Due to multipath's nature, a LUN can have 1+ paths, not just two.
So getline() can be in a ugly loop.
Here is a clear awk version. All you have to consider is how to 
mark the LUN line, the SIZE line, and the PATH lines.

```
awk '/\(.*\)/ {lu=$0} /^\[size/ {size=$0} $2 ~ /sd/ {print lu, size, $0}'
```

But multipath -l can have far more complicated info, like policies, params, etc.

Answer (score 0):

This is a generic solution to a whole class of problems similar to yours - namely parsing record sets that span multiple lines but the line count might differ among record sets.

```
sed '/([0-9a-f]\{33\})/ i \\' input_file | \
  awk '
    BEGIN {RS=""; FS="\n"}
    {for(i=3; i<=NF; i++) {print $1,$2,$i}}
  '
```

gives

```
temp (360a98000572d4d2d5834566c64536b46) dm-4 NETAPP,LUN [size=20G] 2:0:0:4  sde        8:64  [active][ready]
temp (360a98000572d4d2d5834566c64536b46) dm-4 NETAPP,LUN [size=20G] 1:0:0:4  sdm        8:192 [active][ready]
redo (360a98000572d4d2d5834566c646c366c) dm-3 NETAPP,LUN [size=5.0G] 2:0:0:3  sdd        8:48  [active][ready]
redo (360a98000572d4d2d5834566c646c366c) dm-3 NETAPP,LUN [size=5.0G] 1:0:0:3  sdl        8:176 [active][ready]
```

---

#### Properties of this solution

- identifies a record on the hex digest
- handles 1+ path
- easily extended to implement furter logic in awk because each multipath record is seen as  a record in awk

#### Explanation

Imagine your input data looked the following:

```
temp (360a98000572d4d2d5834566c64536b46) dm-4 NETAPP,LUN
[size=20G]
2:0:0:4  sde        8:64  [active][ready]
1:0:0:4  sdm        8:192 [active][ready]

redo (360a98000572d4d2d5834566c646c366c) dm-3 NETAPP,LUN
[size=5.0G]
2:0:0:3  sdd        8:48  [active][ready]
1:0:0:3  sdl        8:176 [active][ready]
```

That would be easy to parse with awk.
You would just tell awk that ..

1. each record is separated by a blank line
2. each field should be just a whole line itself
3. then, for your desired result, print the combination "first line, second line, i.th line" until all lines (fields) are exhausted

That is exactly what the above awk-code is doing:
The line `BEGIN {RS=""; FS="\n"}` sets record sep. to a blank line and the field sep. to a linebreak.
The line `{for(i=3; i<=NF; i++) {print $1,$2,$i}}` does then exactly what I outlined before under 3..

**All you need now is to introduce blank lines to separate your records**
For this task I use sed. I just need an anchor to spot the the lines to introduce blank lines before. Here I use the **hex digest in parentheses**. I assume its always 33 chars long.

Answer (score 0):

**EDIT:**

```
awk '/\[size=.*G\]/ { array[prev]++ } { prev = $0 } FNR!=NR { if ($0 in array) { line = $0; getline; line = line FS $0; next } else { print line, $0 } }' file.txt{,}
```

Explanation:

```
## file.txt{,}    
## this is bash shorthand for reading the same file twice

## { prev = $0 }
## keep track of the last line

## /\[size=.*G\]/ { array[prev]++ }
## if the 'size' pattern is found, add the previous line to an array
## now we have an array of lines to search for

## FNR!=NR
## perform the following actions on the second file only

## if ($0 in array)
## if the line is one of our lines that we're searching for

## line = $0; getline; line = line FS $0; next
## store the line, get the next line join it up and go onto the next record

## else { print line, $0 }
## otherwise print out the 'line' and subsequent data
```

Results:

```
temp (360a98000572d4d2d5834566c64536b46) dm-4 NETAPP,LUN [size=20G] 2:0:0:4  sde        8:64  [active][ready]
temp (360a98000572d4d2d5834566c64536b46) dm-4 NETAPP,LUN [size=20G] 1:0:0:4  sdm        8:192 [active][ready]
redo (360a98000572d4d2d5834566c646c366c) dm-3 NETAPP,LUN [size=5.0G] 2:0:0:3  sdd        8:48  [active][ready]
redo (360a98000572d4d2d5834566c646c366c) dm-3 NETAPP,LUN [size=5.0G] 1:0:0:3  sdl        8:176 [active][ready]
```

Comment: This worked pretty good with a couple servers I tested against, but then I found a server whose multipath is misconfigured resulting in Netapp, Lun  not being present.  With the additional information I provided in the post, is it possible to modify your awk line to work based upon [size=xG]?